# How to initialize view model in data attributes?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have View Model as shown below:

```
  public class ViewModel {
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
  }
```

As per my requirement, there is no need to have  tag. Just I need set with other server side data. So I'm trying to initialize in data attributes in the button tag like :

```html
@model ViewModel
<form>
  @if(someCondition){
  <button data-model="{StartDate='*true logic value*',EndDate='*true logic value*',Description='*true logic value*'}" class="form-submit">
    submit
  </button>
  } else{
  <button data-model="{StartDate='*false logic value*',EndDate='*false logic value*',Description='*false logic value*'}" class="form-submit">
    submit
  </button>
  }
</form>
```

```js
$('.form-submit').click(function() {
  var departure = $(this).data('model');
  var parsedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(departure));
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "//some Url",
    data: parsedData,
    success: function(response) {}
  });
});
```

But When it is submitted, in the Controller View model data is coming as nulls.

What did I wrong?

Comment: Not tested, but should work with `data-model="@Json.Encode(Model)"` and then just `var departure = $(this).data('model');` and `data: data,`

Comment: data-model has to be initialized with individual values as I mentioned in the question

Comment: Then create one for each property of the model.